# To normalize in a given length, should the wavefunction at the endpoints be zero?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, momentum, wavefunction, boundary-conditions

I have an assignment question:

> A free particle is moving in $+x$ direction with a linear momentum $p$. What is the wave function of the particle normalized in a length $L$?

Do I need to use the boundary condition  that $f(0)=f(L)=0$?

Answer (score 1):

No, when you normalize to a length $L$ that only means you should use a region of length $L$ to do the normalization integral.
$$\int_{x_0}^{x_0 + L} \lvert\psi(x)\rvert^2\,\mathrm{d}x = 1$$
Here $x_0$ can be anything. It shouldn't matter what it is because, presumably, you are assuming the wavefunction is periodic with spatial period $L$. There is no need to impose any boundary condition other than that.

Comment: So, should I just normalize exp(-i(p/h)) which gives me f(x) = (1/sqrt(L)) exp(-i(p/h))?

Comment: Why should the wave function of a particle be periodic? It must go to zero at infinity for a particle.

Comment: @Lelouch If it has definite momentum then it can't be spatially localised - the solution is instead a plane wave.